# Netezza SQL script format

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, netezza

I want to write a SQL Script (block of code) with the DECLARE/BEGIN/END and then execute it, But I don't want it to be a store procedure. In oracle or SQL Server I can save the file as .sql file and then execute it. In Netezza this does not work. Any pointer that shows how to run a normal DECLARE/BEGIN/END block of SQL code would help.

For example, how would I execute this block of code in Netezza with out creating a store procedure. I want to save the file on my PC and execute it when I need to.

```
declare
   cursor c1 is SELECT DISTICT sdogid from POLYGON_SDOGEOM;
   gid number;
   i number; 
begin
     i := 0;
     for r in c1 loop
       begin
        gid:= r.sdo_gid;
        sdo_admin.update_index_fixed('POLYGON', gid, 15, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE);
        exeption when others then
          dbms_output.put_line('error for gid'||to_char(gid)||':  '||SQLERRM );
       end;
       i:=  i + 1;
       if i = 50 then
          commit;
          i:= 0;
       end if;
     endloop;
commit;
end;
/
```

Comment: Have you considered using SQLCMD in Powershell? Is Powershell available in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you cannot do that.  What you are wanting to do here is run a procedural variant of SQL outside of a stored procedure, which is not part of the ANSI standard that Netezza (and its progenitor, PostgreSQL) strives to adhere to.

This sort of procedural logic would have to be implemented in a stored procedure.